# How to check whether a particular port is open on a machine from a shell script and perform action based on that?

Tags: bash, shell-script

I am running my below shell script on a machine on which c++ application server is running on port 8080 and in the shell script I am executing an URL and stores the response coming from that URL in DATA variable.

But suppose if the same app server is down, then it will not be able to execute the URL and then it will print out `Retrying Again` and sleep for 30 seconds and then execute the same url again.

```
#!/bin/bash

HOSTNAME=$hostname
DATA=""
RETRY=15

echo $HOSTNAME

while [ $RETRY -gt 0 ]
do
    DATA=$(wget -O - -q -t 1 http://$HOSTNAME:8080/beat)
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]
    then
        break
    else
        echo "Retrying Again" >&2

        # restart the server

        let RETRY-=1
        sleep 30
    fi
done

echo "Server is UP"
```

And here `HOSTNAME` is the local hostname of the server on which I  am running my above shell script.

**Problem Statement:-**

Now what I am trying to do is, if the server is down, then it will print out `Retrying Again` so after that I want to check whether  port `8080` is opened on `$HOSTNAME` or not. If not, then it means server is down so I want to restart the server by executing this command and then sleep for 30 seconds as shown above in the shell script.

```
/opt/app/test/start_stop.sh start
```

Is this possible to do here in my above shell script?

I am running this shell script on Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

The program `lsof` allows you to check which processes are using which ressources, like files or ports.

To show which processes are listening on port 8080:

`lsof -Pi :8080 -sTCP:LISTEN`

In your case, you want to test whether a process is listening on 8080 - the return value of this command tells you just that. It also prints the pid of the process.

`lsof -Pi :8080 -sTCP:LISTEN -t`

If you need just the test, with no output, redirect it to `/dev/null`:

```
if lsof -Pi :8080 -sTCP:LISTEN -t >/dev/null ; then
    echo "running"
else
    echo "not running"
fi
```

If you use multiple host names with multiple IP addresses locally, specify the hostname too like
`lsof -Pi @someLocalName:8080 -sTCP:LISTEN`

Comment: Thanks Volker. I tried this `lsof -i :8080 -sTCP:LISTEN` and I am not getting anything on the console but if I am trying this `netstat -tulpn | grep :8080` then I get my process which is running on port 8080 why is it so?

Comment: What is the output of `netstat -tulpn | grep :8080`?

Comment: This is what I get with netstat -  

`david@machineA:/home/david$ netstat -tulpn | grep :8080
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8080            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      27530/test_server`

Comment: Strange, if I try similar things it works. Could be related to IPv6... hmmm.

Comment: Is it listed with `lsof -iTCP -sTCP:LISTEN | grep 8080`?

Comment: You probably want to use `lsof -i -P | grep 8080`. Port 8080 is probably showing up as a proxy port of some sort.

Comment: @Lawrence Regarding proxy: netstat shows the actual process `test_server` on port 8080, strange that lsof does not match it...

Comment: @VolkerSiegel I meant that port 8080 is commonly assigned to a proxy or web server, so running `lsof -i` would show something like `test_server    1473     user   11u  IPv4    9822      0t0  TCP *:http-alt (LISTEN)` rather than the output of `test_server    1473     user   11u  IPv4    9822      0t0  TCP *:8080 (LISTEN)` that you're expecting

Comment: @VolkerSiegel I tried using this `lsof -iTCP -sTCP:LISTEN | grep 8080` and still it doesn't work for me somehow but netstat works fine.

Comment: @user2809564 try `lsof -i -P | grep 8080`

Comment: Yes it shows  me few results on the screen not one. It looks like, it shows the other machine which are making call to my app server machine as well where I am running lsof command?

Comment: @user2809564 yes, it will show current connections. If you use `lsof -i -P -sTCP:LISTEN | grep 8080` it should show you just the open port.

Comment: Yup that works fine. How does this work now? Can you explain me little bit, just for my understanding purpose?

Comment: What is the output of the command? I'm trying to understand what was difficult. And: the grep should be `...| grep ':8080 '` to not match other ports (like 18080), pids or device numbers.

Comment: `man lsof` should explain the parameters fully, but in short - `-i` is get all open IPv4/6 ports, `-P` is show port numbers rather than service, and `-s TCP:LISTEN` is select TCP ports that are listening

Comment: @Lawrence Oh, that was the the problem: `$ grep 8080 /etc/services` gives
`http-alt 8080/tcp webcache`. I did not expect 8080 is a well defined port. It was not when I was young ;)

Comment: @VolkerSiegel Bingo :) I always use `-P` when using `lsof` :)

Comment: @Lawrence one more thing, if I run this  command `lsof -i -P -sTCP:LISTEN | grep 8080` as a user who started the `test_server` then it shows the open port on my console properly but if I run that command as a different user, then it doesn't work? Is it normal behavior? Since with netstat it works fine with both the user's.

Comment: @user2809564 `lsof` will only be able to get ports opened by the user that is running `lsof`. If you need to run it as a different user, user `sudo lsof`

Comment: @user2809564 Not important, but does `lsof -Pi :8080 -sTCP:LISTEN` show something now? I'd update the answer if I know what works.

Comment: Hmm. `lsof -i :445` on my Ubuntu 14.04 returns the listening port, I didn't need to add the `-P` option.

Comment: @VolkerSiegel Yes it does show it now with that command `lsof -Pi :8080 -sTCP:LISTEN`

Comment: Good, that's much cleaner in matching what you really want, compared to using grep on output. Maybe it was related to which user can see which, let's check... Oh, indeed, it lists only own listening processes by default. That explains much.

Answer (score 30):

Simplest way in bash. Test if your port is open.

```
(echo >/dev/tcp/localhost/8080) &>/dev/null && echo "TCP port 8080 open" || echo "TCP port 8080 not open"
```

Replace the port with what you are testing.

Or you can use nc.

```
nc -vz 127.0.0.1 8080
```

Returns:

> Connection to 127.0.0.1 8080 port [tcp/*] succeeded

Comment: `nc` is a great solution for my use case; thanks for suggesting

Comment: Shouldn't the `echo` solution employ the `-n` option? Otherwise `echo` would probably not only establish a connection, but also send a newline. Am I wrong?

Comment: `nc` is the best solution for cross platform compatibility.

Answer (score 8):

Elaborating on RJ's answer which notes `nc` is also useful... Not only is `nc` useful for quick command-line query

```
❯ nc -z -v -w5 127.0.0.1 8080
localhost [127.0.0.1] 8080 (http-alt) : Connection refused
```

but it can be used without -v if the human-readability thing isn't what you're after -- e.g., for use in a script (the exit code will indicate whether the port is open or closed).

```
❯ nc -z 127.0.0.1 8080

❯ echo $?             
1
```